# Fitting image size across screen resolutions

Tags: css, html, background, width

I have a div tag like

```
<div id="MainMenu1" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane"></div>
```

This div is associated with a css like

```
#MainMenu1 
{
height:53px;
background: url(../images/top_banner.png) no-repeat;
background-position:center;
margin:auto;
width:100%;
border:0;
}
```

I see that the background image is fine on a smaller screen but on a wider screen, it occupies only the center position. I want the image to occupy the full screen even on wider screens and I do not want the image to "repeat".
How would I do this?

Comment: what happens if you take background-position:center; off the CSS?

Comment: @Chin Image aligns with the left if i remove center.

Answer (score 1):

```
#MainMenu1 
{
height:53px;
margin:auto;
width:100%;
border:0;
background: url(../images/top_banner.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Try this. It works perfectly for me. It should fit the background perfectly in the center and reasonably stretch it to whatever screen size the website is being viewed on.

Answer (score 0):

You can either let the image repeat meaning it covers the whole space or use `background-size: cover` which will scale it to cover the whole area while keeping the original aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: This works in mozilla. But I want in IE8. Forgot to specify that in the question.

Comment: Use a bigger image then? I'm not aware of any way this can be done pre IE9 without repeating.